# Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a simple java program trying to connect to the local instance of neo4j to create a sample database to play with but I keep getting;

```
Exception: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory, /home/mleonard/mbig/neodb/testeroo
Trace:[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7ce7d377
```

The stack trace is useless and the error is also not overly helpful.

```
The server is up and running
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
2015-08-11 15:28:06.466-0400 INFO  Setting startup timeout to 120000ms
2015-08-11 15:28:23.311-0400 INFO  Successfully started database
2015-08-11 15:28:25.920-0400 INFO  Starting HTTP on port 7474 (24 threads available)
2015-08-11 15:28:26.972-0400 INFO  Enabling HTTPS on port 7473
2015-08-11 15:28:28.247-0400 INFO  Mounting static content at /webadmin
2015-08-11 15:28:28.704-0400 INFO  Mounting static content at /browser
2015-08-11 15:28:30.321-0400 ERROR The class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter is not assignable to the class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter. This class is ignored.
2015-08-11 15:28:31.677-0400 ERROR The class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter is not assignable to the class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter. This class is ignored.
2015-08-11 15:28:32.165-0400 ERROR The class org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter is not assignable to the class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter. This class is ignored.
2015-08-11 15:28:33.031-0400 INFO  Remote interface ready and available at http://localhost:7474/
```

And I can see that the database is created as the files and folders for the new database are created.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Main {

    private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType
    {
        WORKS,
        FRIENDS,
        NEMISIS
    }

    public  static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Starting ARM4J");
        GraphDatabaseService db = null ;
        try
        {           
            db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File("/home/mleonard/mbig/neodb/testeroo"))
                                            .loadPropertiesFromFile("/home/mleonard/mbig/neo4j-community-2.3.0-M02/conf/neo4j.properties")
                                            .newGraphDatabase();

            /*
            try( Transaction tx = db.beginTx() )
            {               
                Node matty = db.createNode();
                matty.setProperty("name", "Matthew");
                matty.setProperty("age", "31");
                matty.setProperty("sex", "male");

                Node jay = db.createNode();
                jay.setProperty("name", "Jay");;
                jay.setProperty("age", "35");
                jay.setProperty("sex", "male");

                org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship r = matty.createRelationshipTo(jay, RelTypes.WORKS);
                r.setProperty("years", "2");

                tx.success();
            }
            */          
        }
        catch(Exception x)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + x.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Trace:" + x.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if( db != null )
            {
                db.shutdown();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Stopping ARM4J");
    }
}
```

Comment: what jars do you have on your classpath? Paste the relevant snippet from your `graph.db/messages.log`.